# I want to Synchronize mysql DB from a remote PC to Local PC, all time.

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, mysql-workbench

I am using Mysql, I have two DB in two different system. I want my local DB to be synced with remote DB. both the Schema will be having same table and column.

whenever a change occurs in remote DB that change / Update should happen in my Local DB.

How to do it???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If the local DB is a read-only copy, you only need to enable binary logging on the remote, and setup the local as a slave.

Comment: How can i do it in my remote PC. I am new to DB,Please give me some link.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need is a replication setup using a multi-source setup as described in the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-multi-source.html).

Comment: Uhm, don't you see the link in my answer? The docs include even a  tutorial.

Comment: ya mike, I haven't tried that yet... thanks for your response..... Once i did ill update you....